# How to silence a powershell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that (by necessity) has to call a rather noisy set of other cmdlets.  I'd like to the printing from the other cmdlets to not be displayed so I only see the status messages from my own script.

I've tried `> $null` and `| Out-Null`, but those only swallow returned values, not text printed via `Write-Host`.  How can I hide/prevent text being printed "down the stack"?

Comment: Avoiding `Write-Host` is hard, but you could do it by running those cmdlets as a job. A job would be a separate host process, so no output. `$Job = Start-Job -Scriptblock {Noisy-Cmdlet};Wait-Job $Job`

Comment: `&{Make-Noise} *> $null`

Comment: `Write-Host` output cannot be redirected unless the code producing it is run in a different process (so that Windows merges the console output back into that process's STDOUT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've read your post correctly, you'd like to silence the Write-Host cmdlet. If we consider command precedence, we know that functions will be run before cmdlets, if they have the *same name*. Therefore, I'd recommend you create a Write-Host function that doesn't write anything. Here's an example that highlights this possibility.

[image]

Comment: This would effectively silence _all_ output, correct?  My own script still prints stuff that I want to see.  How can I work around that?  Is it possible to set a new name to the current Write-Host, then override it with a dud?

Comment: You should attempt to avoid Write-Host. Use Write-Output -InputObject <Your Message Here> for things you don't want to silence. Either that, or use Write-Host (against my better judgement) this way, in order to see it: Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Host -Object <Your Message Here>. Command precedence doesn't remove the original Write-Host cmdlet. It just runs the function of the same name instead of the cmdlet. You can still you it if you add the module name and a backslash, as I demonstrated above.

Comment: Cool, I like that approach.  It's working for some writes to the console, but others appear to coming from `Console.WriteLine()`s in DLLs within the cmdlets.  What can I do about those?

Comment: Okay, I just discovered `System.Console.SetOut()`, which solves that issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try to define your dummy function `Write-Host` before calling noisy cmdlets, e.g.

```
    function Write-Host {}
```

If they call `Write-Host` literally then this should help.

Comment: Is there any way to "undefine" my own afterward?

Comment: `Remove-Item function:Write-Host`